# Use SharePoint Groups in Provider Hosted App (MVC5.0)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app, authorization

I am working on a Provider Hosted App (MVC5.0), but I want to make use of SharePoint Groups. Is this possible to achieve, and how to determine whether a user is in a specific group?

Comment: You will need to write CSOM code to check if user exists in a group.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to check if a user exists in a particular group or not using CSOM.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection");
GroupCollection collGroup = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
Group oGroup = collGroup.GetById(7);
UserCollection collUser = oGroup.Users;

clientContext.Load(collUser,
    users => users.Include(
        user => user.Title,
        user => user.LoginName,
        user => user.Email));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (User oUser in collUser)
{
    if (oUser.LoginName == "YourUserName")
    {
        //User Exits
    }
}
```